# How to validate questionnaire generated from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, validation, material-design

I have questionnaire in node.js generated from database, now questions could be any random type of "multiple choice, single choice, yes-no and text" validation should be simple to check is every question answered.
I know how to validate form but the problem is that my form has dialog for name,surname and email so I need first part to be validated in jQuery/javascript on button `id="show-dialog"` as well as my dialog with name,surname and email on second button.

My view (start.ejs) look like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1><%= title %></h1>
<form name="questionsForm" id="questionsForm" method="post" action="/save">
<% pitanja.forEach(function(pitanje) { %>
    <input type="hidden" name="pitanje_id" value="<%= pitanje.id %>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="upitnik_id" id="upitnik" value="<%= pitanje.upitnik_id %>" >
<% switch (pitanje.tip_pitanja_id) {
    case 1: %>
<div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-card__supporting-text">
<h4> <%= pitanje.tekst %> </h4>
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="odgovor_tekst" name="<%= pitanje.id %>">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="odgovor_tekst">Tekst...</label>
</div>
</div>

<% break; %>
<% case 2: %>
<div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-card__supporting-text">
    <h4> <%= pitanje.tekst %> </h4>
<ul class="demo-list-control mdl-list">
    <li class="mdl-list__item">
         <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
        <label>Da</label>
             </span>
        <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action">
            <label class="demo-list-radio mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="list-option-yes">
        <input  id="list-option-yes" class="mdl-radio__button" type="radio" name="<%= pitanje.id %>" value="true">
            </label>
        </span>
    </li>

    <li class="mdl-list__item">
         <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
        <label>Ne</label>
             </span>
        <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action">
            <label class="demo-list-radio mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="list-option-no">
        <input  id="list-option-no" class="mdl-radio__button" type="radio" name="<%= pitanje.id %>" value="false">
            </label>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

<% break; %>
<% case 3: %>
<div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-card__supporting-text">
<h4> <%= pitanje.tekst %> </h4>
<ul class="demo-list-control mdl-list">
    <% odgovori.forEach(function(odgovor) { %>
    <% if(pitanje.id == odgovor.pitanje_id){ %>

    <li class="mdl-list__item">
        <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="checkbox-<%= odgovor.id %>">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-<%= odgovor.id %>" name="<%= pitanje.id %>"   value="<%= odgovor.tekst %>" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
            <span class="mdl-checkbox__label"><%= odgovor.tekst %></span>
        </label>
    </li>
    <% }%>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
</div>
<% break; %>
<% case 4: %>
<div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-card__supporting-text">
<h4> <%= pitanje.tekst %> </h4>
<ul class="demo-list-control mdl-list" >
    <% odgovori.forEach(function(odgovor) { %>
    <% if(pitanje.id == odgovor.pitanje_id){ %>

    <li class="mdl-list__item">
         <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
        <label><%= odgovor.tekst %></label>
             </span>
        <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action">
            <label class="demo-list-radio mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="list-option-<%=odgovor.id%>">
        <input  id="list-option-<%=odgovor.id%>" class="mdl-radio__button" type="radio" name="<%= pitanje.id %>" value="<%= odgovor.tekst %>">
            </label>

        </span>
    </li>
    <% }%>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
</div>
<% break; %>
<% } %>
<% }); %>  
</br> 
<button id="show-dialog" type="button" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--accent">Sačuvaj</button>
<dialog class="mdl-dialog">
    <h4 class="mdl-dialog__title">Unesite vaše podatke</h4>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__content">

        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="ime" name="ime">
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="ime">Ime</label>
            <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Greška!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="prezime" name="prezime">
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="prezime">Prezime</label>
            <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Greška!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="email" name="email">
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="email">Email</label>
            <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Greška!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
        <input type="submit" value="Spremi" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored pull" >
        <button type="button" class="mdl-button close">Prekini</button>
    </div>
</dialog>   
</form>  
<script>
    var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
    var showDialogButton = document.querySelector('#show-dialog');
    if (! dialog.showModal) {
        dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
    }
    showDialogButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        dialog.showModal();
    });
    dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
        dialog.close();
    });
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Node.js route start.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    var pg = require('pg');
    var connect = "postgres://postgres:postgres11@localhost:5432/Questionnaire"
    var client = new pg.Client(connect);
    // connect to our database
    var odgovori;
    client.connect();

    client.query('SELECT * FROM predefinisani_odgovori WHERE(Select id FROM pitanja Where upitnik_id=$1 AND id=pitanje_id) = pitanje_id order by random() limit 1000;',[req.params.id], function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if(result!=null)
            odgovori = result.rows;
    });

    client.query('SELECT * FROM pitanja WHERE upitnik_id=$1',[req.params.id], function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var all = result.rows;

        res.render('start',{pitanja: all,title:'Questionnaire',odgovori:odgovori})

        // execute a query on our database

        client.end(function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            });
        });
    });
    module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in javascript is here:

```
var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
if (! dialog.showModal) {
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
}
dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
    dialog.close();
});
function validateQue() {
var questions=document.getElementsByClassName("que");
var countValid=0;
for(var i=0;i<questions.length;i++){
    var inputs=questions[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
    var id = questions[i].id.replace('que','');
    var lbl = document.getElementById('lbl'+id);
    for(var j=0;j<inputs.length;j++){
        var isAnswered = false;
        if(inputs[j].type=="radio"){
            if(inputs[j].checked)
            {
                isAnswered=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(inputs[j].type=="checkbox"){
            if(inputs[j].checked)
            {
                isAnswered=true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    var textarea=questions[i].getElementsByClassName("text");
    for(var k=0;k<textarea.length;k++){
        if(textarea[k].value==null ||textarea[k].value=="" || textarea[k].value.trim().length==0)
        {
        }else {
            isAnswered=true;
        }
    }
    if(isAnswered==true){
        countValid++;
        if(lbl!=null) {
            lbl.innerText = "";
        }
    }else{
        if(lbl!=null) {
            lbl.innerText = "*";
        }
    }
}
if(countValid==questions.length){
    dialog.showModal();
}else {
}
}
function validateUser() {
    var ime=document.getElementById("ime");
    var prezime=document.getElementById("prezime");
    var email=document.getElementById("email");
    var ime_error = document.getElementById("ime_error");
    var prezime_error = document.getElementById("prezime_error");
    var email_error = document.getElementById("email_error");
    var countValid=0;
    if(ime.value==null ||ime.value==""|| ime.value.trim().length==0)
    {
        ime.parentElement.className += ' is-invalid';
        ime_error.innerText="Ime je obavezno polje";
    }else {
        ime.parentElement.className.replace(' is-invalid','');
        ime_error.innerText="";
        countValid++;
    }
    if(prezime.value==null ||prezime.value=="" || prezime.value.trim().length==0)
    {
        prezime_error.innerText="Prezime je obavezno polje";
        prezime.parentElement.className += ' is-invalid';
    }else {
        prezime.parentElement.className.replace(' is-invalid','');
        prezime_error.innerText="";
        countValid++;
    }
    if(email.value==null ||email.value==""|| email.value.trim().length==0)
    {
        email.parentElement.className += ' is-invalid';
        email_error.innerText="E-mail je obavezno polje";
    }else {
        if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email.value))
        {
            email_error.innerText="";
            email.parentElement.className.replace(' is-invalid','');
            countValid++;
        }else {
            email_error.innerText="E-mail mora biti u formatu: example@live.com";
            email.parentElement.className += ' is-invalid';
        }
    }
    if(countValid==3){
        return true;
    }else {
    }
    return false;
}
```